# How to use a caching system (memcached, redis or any other) with slim 3

Tags: php, redis, memcached, slim-3

I browsed the internet and didn't find much information on how to use any caching library with Slim framework 3.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Try this, for slim 2: https://gist.github.com/hising/ddece8c92bcd09df83fdcf9890fc0dd3

Comment: When you say `use a caching library with slim 3` you mean you want to add a caching library to your application and then get help from the framework? I use caching in my slim 3 applications but I use it manually wherever I see fit, no special treatment from slim. I mean I generate unique cache-keys myself, check if the item is in the pool, etc. I can help if you give some more information.

Comment: It would be wonderful to get some information on using caching in a project from you @Nima (using cache for the first time).  How can I use caching with or without any library ?

Comment: Can you guide me how to use caching manually @Nima

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use `symfony/cache` with Slim 3. You can use any other cache library, but I give an example setup for this specific library. And I should mention, this is actually independent of Slim or any other framework.

First you need to include this library in your project, I recommend using composer. I also will iinclude `predis/predis` to be able to use Redis adapter:

`composer require symfony/cache predis/predis`

Then I'll use Dependency Injection Container to setup cache pool to make it available to other objects which need to use caching features:

```
// If you created your project using slim skeleton app
// this should probably be placed in depndencies.php
$container['cache'] = function ($c) {
    $config = [
        'schema' => 'tcp',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 6379,
        // other options
    ];
    $connection = new Predis\Client($config);
    return new Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter($connection);
}
```

Now you have a cache item pool in `$container['cache']` which has methods defined in PSR-6.

Here is a sample code using it:

```
class SampleClass {

    protected $cache;
    public function __construct($cache) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        $item = $this->cache->getItem('unique-cache-key');
        if ($item->isHit()) {
            return 'I was previously called at ' . $item->get();
        }
        else {
            $item->set(time());
            $item->expiresAfter(3600);
            $this->cache->save($item);

            return 'I am being called for the first time, I will return results from cache for the next 3600 seconds.';
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you want to create new instance of SampleClass you should pass this cache item pool from the DIC, for example in a route callback:

```
$app->get('/foo', function (){
    $bar = new SampleClass($this->get('cache'));
    return $bar->doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$memcached = new \Memcached();

$memcached->addServer($cachedHost, $cachedPort);

$metadataCache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache();
$metadataCache->setMemcached($memcached);

$queryCache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache();
$queryCache->setMemcached($memcached);
```